# How to find out if a sequence with exponentiation in fraction is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, roots

I need to find the convergence of this function:
$\sum^{\infty}_{x=1}{\frac{(x+1)^{x^2}}{x^{x^2}2^x}}$

Now my problem is, I have no clue how to do this (I tried the root-test and it did not work out)...

I thought the direct-comparison-test might do the job, but I am somehow not able to use it here, because I don't know how.

Any help would be gratefully accepted... =)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Your series is

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1+1/n)^{n^2}}{2^n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{[(1+1/n)^n]^n}{2^n}.$$

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer... but how did you get to this term? Your term is convergent. But now I plotted the original term and it does not converge... could you explain that to me? I am a bit confused =D

Comment: You don't understand why the series on the right is the same as your series?

Comment: thats my problem, yes...?

Comment: I'm just using $a^{x^2}/\,b^{x^2} = (a/b)^{x^2}.$